# Pattern matching of Arrays

Tags: arrays, haskell

Haskell provides in `Data.Array.IArray` a type `Array` of immutable arrays. This allows to use arrays inside functional code. Is it possible to match `Array`s with patterns, the same way it is possible for lists?

I would like the following code to work...

```
function :: Ix a => Array a b -> ...

function [| x |]         = ... -- matches if arg has one element
function [| x, y |]      = ... -- matches if arg has two elements
function [| x, ..., y |] = ... -- matches if arg has more than 3 elements and
                               -- binds the first and last element with x and y
```

Note : this feature exists in the Rust language, see https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/slice-patterns.html

Comment: I don’t think that `Data.Array.IArray` provides any way to do this built-in, but with the [`PatternSynonyms`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#pattern-synonyms) and [`ViewPatterns`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#view-patterns) extensions, you could probably implement something like this yourself. You could also just use guards instead of patterns for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to answer this for `Data.Vector` or `Data.Vector.Unboxed` because I don't think the question really makes sense in terms of the multidimensional `Data.Array.IArray`...

You can do something sort of like `ViewL` and `ViewR` in `Data.Sequence`. Adapting that, you could have

```
data ViewL a
    = EmptyL        -- ^ empty vector
    | a :< Vector a -- ^ leftmost element and the rest of the vector

data ViewR a
    = EmptyR        -- ^ empty vector
    | Vector a :> a -- ^ rest of the vector and the rightmost element
```

Then, you could define functions

```
viewl :: Vector a -> ViewL a
viewl v | null v = EmptyL
        | otherwise = head v :< tail v 

viewr :: Vector a -> ViewR a
viewr v | null v = EmptyR
        | otherwise = init v :> last v 

viewlr :: Vector a -> (ViewL a, ViewR a)
viewlr v = (viewl v, viewr v) -- or `viewl &&& viewr` if you like Control.Arrows
```

And use these with the [ViewPatterns](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#view-patterns) extension:

```
function :: Vector a -> ...
function (viewl -> x :< EmptyL)      = ... -- matches if arg has one element
function (viewl -> x :< y:< EmptyL)  = ... -- matches if arg has two elements
function (viewlr -> (x :< _, _ :> y) = ... -- matches `x` and `y` to the first and
                                           -- last elements
function (viewlr -> (x :< _ :< _ :< _, _ :> y) = ... -- matches if arg has more
                                                     -- than 3 elements and binds 
                                                     -- the first and last element
                                                     -- with x and y
```

Since `tail` and `init` are O(1) slices for `Data.Vector`, this lazily looks at only as many elements of the vector as needed.

Answer (score 2):

First, note that Haskell arrays may be multi-dimensional.

You could write your example function like this:

```
import Data.Array.IArray
import Data.Ix

foo arr
  | first == last = print x      -- single element case
  | otherwise     = print (x,y)  -- more than one element case
  where (first,last) = bounds arr
        x = arr ! first
        y = arr ! last
```

Comment: In fact, I think the `Ix` type class specifies how the indices of an array are mapped into contiguous integers.